# Issue with Jquery slide pannel display format?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I need the side panel in the following format, for that I have used the list but the I didn't get the require format. Which tag should I need to use to get the following format. Also I need the panel should open below the header which is shown in below figure,

[image]

My code is as follows,

```
<div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-display="reveal" data-position="left">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-about ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='test()'>test</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-privacy ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='test1()'>test1</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-reset ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='test2()'>test2</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-feedback ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='test3()'>tets3</a>
</div>

<a href="#navpanel" id="bars-button" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a demo for you.

For the Panel to open beneath the Header adjusting the panels (z-index) value to a lower one than of the headers will achieve that.

Adjusted some other CSS values to change the bullet and border color and added Jquery script to dynamically change the color of the bullet when you click on a panel item.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/HE96S/

**Demo with full page Overlay**

http://jsfiddle.net/88aka4r1/

**The css additions**

```
@font-face {

  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v5/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');

}

.ui-panel-display-overlay {

z-index: 100;

}

.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn, html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn, html .ui-body-a .ui-btn, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn, html head+body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:visited, html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn:visited, html .ui-body-a .ui-btn:visited, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:visited, html head+body  {

border-color: #17A3F1;

}

#mypanel li a {  

font-family: 'open sans',arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight:lighter;

}


.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:hover, html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn:hover, html .ui-body-a .ui-btn:hover, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:hover, html head+body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a:hover {

border-color: #17A3F1;

}

li, .aa > .ui-custom-icon:after {

background-color: rgba(15, 101, 229, 0.3);

}

#overlay  {

   width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: url('http://s23.postimg.org/5q0dfwmbr/overlay.png') repeat 0 0;;
    display: none;

}

html, body {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('ul > li').click(function() { 

  $('ul > li').removeClass('aa'); 
  $(this).addClass('aa');

});

var $overlay_wrapper;

function show_overlay() {

    if ( !$overlay_wrapper ) append_overlay();
    $overlay_wrapper.fadeIn(700);

}

function hide_overlay() {

    $overlay_wrapper.fadeOut(500);

}

function append_overlay() {

    $overlay_wrapper = $('<div id="overlay"></div>').appendTo( $('.ui-mobile .ui-page') );

}


$( "#mypanel" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {

    show_overlay();

});

$( "#mypanel" ).on( "panelbeforeclose", function( event, ui ) {

        hide_overlay();

});
```

Comment: That is what exactly I need thank you. but one thing, If I open panel then the main page should cover with gray color overlay as shown in my pic. If possible then me how to do that. If not no issues. I will accept your answer

Comment: Ok dude i done that for you so check the demo link. That was easy to do after checking this tutorial. -- http://interactivevolcano.com/grayed-out-overlays-with-jquery-and-css